# How to resolve the compilation error here - for the observer pattern in C++?

Tags: c++

I get the following compilation error here. Why can't the derived class access another derived class method. Although the method is public. I am confused here. Please help.

> /export/home/joshis1/Dropbox/Design_Patterns_UML/ObserverPattern/ObserverPatternProgram-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_4_in_PATH__System__Release/../ObserverPatternProgram/UpdateReceiver.h:43:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘IPublisher::registerObserver(UpdateReceiver* const)’

I have a publisher class - Interface -

```
class ISubscriber;

/** Interface **/


class IPublisher
{

public:
   virtual void registerObserver(ISubscriber *observer) = 0;
   virtual void unregisterObserver(ISubscriber &observer) = 0;
   virtual void notifyObserver() = 0;
   virtual void setBaudRate(int newBaudRate) = 0;
   virtual void setAspectRatio(int newAspectRatio) = 0;
   virtual void setVolumeLevel(int newVolume) = 0;
};

//////////////////////////////////////

class ISubscriber;

class UpdateManager: public IPublisher
{
 private:

    QList<ISubscriber *> subscribers;
    int m_baudRate;
    int m_aspectRatio;
    int m_volumeLevel;

  public:

    UpdateManager()
    {
        qDebug()<<"Update Manager --- Server/Subject Initialized";
        subscribers.clear();

    }

    virtual void registerObserver(ISubscriber *observer)
    {
        subscribers.append(observer);
    }

    virtual void unregisterObserver(ISubscriber *observer)
    {
        int index = subscribers.indexOf(observer);
        subscribers.removeAt(index);
        qWarning()<<"Removed the subscriber Index = "<<index;
    }

    virtual void setBaudRate(int newBaudRate)
    {
        m_baudRate = newBaudRate;
        notifyObserver();

    }

    virtual void setAspectRatio(int newAspectRatio)
    {
        m_aspectRatio = newAspectRatio;
        notifyObserver();

    }

    virtual void setVolumeLevel(int newVolume)
    {
        m_volumeLevel = newVolume;
        notifyObserver();
    }


    virtual void notifyObserver()
    {
#if 0
        foreach( ISubscriber observer, subscribers )
        {
            observer.update(m_baudRate,m_aspectRatio,m_volumeLevel);
        }
 #endif
    }


};
```

///////////////////

I have the observer --

```
/** Subscriber Interface **/
class ISubsrciber
{
   public:

    virtual void update(int baudRate, int AspectRatio, int VolumeLevel) = 0;

};

class UpdateManager;
class ISubsrciber;

#include "IPublisher.h"


class UpdateReceiver: public ISubsrciber
{
 private:
    int m_baudRate;
    int m_aspectRatio;
    int m_volumeLevel;
    int m_receiverNumber;


public:
   // static int updateReceiverTracker;

 /** Update Interface of the client **/

 void update(int baudRate, int AspectRatio, int VolumeLevel)
 {
     m_baudRate = baudRate;
     m_aspectRatio = AspectRatio;
     m_volumeLevel =  VolumeLevel;

     qDebug()<<"The following client number : "<< m_receiverNumber<< " got the update ";
     qDebug()<<"The baudRate is "<<baudRate;
     qDebug()<<"The AspectRatio is"<<AspectRatio;
     qDebug()<<"The VolumeLevel is"<<VolumeLevel;


 }

 /** Constructor -- and registers with the Server or Publisher or UpdateManager **/
 UpdateReceiver(IPublisher *updateManager)
 {
   //m_receiverNumber = UpdateReceiver::updateReceiverTracker++;

    updateManager->registerObserver(this);
 }


};
```

Comment: You have a typo in your forward declarations: first you use  `ISubscriber` and then you use `ISubsrciber`.

Comment: Don't try to implement the Observer pattern yourself. It's too involved to do it properly. Just use a signal/slot library. Boost has one and libsigc++ works well too.

Comment: Is signal slot nothing but a observer pattern?

Comment: @user3629119 Signal/slot is more general than the observer pattern. A descend signal/slot library will handle all the lifetime management issues for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error message you have - you don't have a method (at least in this question) with the signature that your code is apparently looking for. You have:

```
virtual void registerObserver(ISubscriber *observer)
    {
        subscribers.append(observer);
    }
```

Your first file describes an `ISubscriber` but your second file inherits from an `ISubsrciber` (sic).

You have a typo in your file. Change to `ISubscriber` and you should have better luck!

Answer (score 0):

here updateManager->registerObserver(this); you are sending it object of UpdateReceiver while it requires ISubscriber.

Answer (score 0):

class

```
class UpdateReceiver: public ISubsrciber   // wrong 
class UpdateReceiver: public UpdateManager // right
```

should inherit UpdateManager not ISubsrciber?

Answer (score 0):

Well I do see a few problems along your solution. Firstly you do have different forward declarations for the type `ISubscriber` as I stated in my earlier comment. Which results in your program not compiling.

These two wont match for sure.

```
virtual void registerObserver(ISubscriber *observer) {...}
class UpdateReceiver: public ISubsrciber {...}
                                 ^^^^
```

Secondly your `notifyObserver` implementation does need some rethinking as well. But since you kind of commented that code out, I'll leave this one up to you. Just remember that you're holding pointers to `ISubscriber` in your subscriber list when you're trying to iterate/loop over it.

Also the definition of `unregisterObserver` does not match your declaration.

```
virtual void unregisterObserver(ISubscriber &observer) = 0;
virtual void unregisterObserver(ISubscriber *observer) {...}
```

---

**BUT**
I would consider some major refactorings for your code. In my opinion you should not mix up the Interface of the `Observer`pattern with your application logic.

I think your solution should look similar to this. It's not complete and does not use your QT classes tho but you should get the idea. See the [demo](http://ideone.com/vKWx1Q) for a runnable solution.

```
class ISubscriber {
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Publisher {
    std::vector<ISubscriber*> m_observerList;
public:
    virtual void registerSubscriber(ISubscriber& observer);
    virtual void unregisterSubscriber(ISubscriber& observer);
    virtual void notifySubscribers();
};

class UpdateManager : public Publisher {
    int m_baudRate;
    int m_aspectRatio;
    int m_volumeLevel;
public:
    virtual void setBaudRate(int newBaudRate);
    virtual void setAspectRatio(int newAspectRatio);
    virtual void setVolumeLevel(int newVolume);

    int getBaudRate() const;
    int getAspectRatio() const;
    int getVolumeLevel() const;
};

class UpdateReceiver : public ISubscriber {
    UpdateManager& m_manager;
public:
    UpdateReceiver(UpdateManager& manager) : m_manager(manager) {
        m_manager.registerSubscriber(*this);
    }
    virtual void update() {
        // Process the new values
        m_manager.getBaudRate();
        m_manager.getAspectRatio();
        m_manager.getVolumeLevel();
    }
};
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/vKWx1Q)**